# How to configure Denial of Service filters in ODL controller

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty, opendaylight

I am new to ODL controller and the embedded jetty.
I would like to add the DoSFilter in jetty.xml to throttle the REST requests if there is a request flooding.

I tried searching the internet, but has lot of examples for configuring it in web.xml [DoSFilter](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/dos-filter.html) but not found much help for jetty.xml

Any help in configuring DoSFilter in jetty.xml would be of great help.

ODL - Nitrogen version

Jetty - 9.2.21.X version

The following are the options which I have tried so far.

**Filters configured in jetty.xml:**

```xml
    <Get name="handler">
        <Call name="addHandler">
            <Arg>
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">
                    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
                    <Set name="resourceBase">../</Set>
                    <Call name="addFilter">
                        <Arg>
                            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder">
                                <Arg>
                                    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.DoSFilter" />
                                </Arg>
                                <Call name="setInitParameter">
                                    <Arg>maxRequestsPerSec</Arg>
                                    <Arg>30</Arg>
                                </Call>
                                <Call name="setInitParameter">
                                    <Arg>delayMs</Arg>
                                    <Arg>100</Arg>
                                </Call>
                                <Call name="setInitParameter">
                                    <Arg>maxRequestMs</Arg>
                                    <Arg>0</Arg>
                                </Call>
                                <Call name="setInitParameter">
                                    <Arg>maxIdleTrackerMs</Arg>
                                    <Arg>0</Arg>
                                </Call>
                                <Call name="setInitParameter">
                                    <Arg>ipWhitelist</Arg>
                                    <Arg>127.0.0.1</Arg>
                                </Call>
                            </New>
                        </Arg>
                        <Arg>/cxf/*</Arg>
                        <Arg>
                            <Call class="java.util.EnumSet" name="of">
                                <Arg>
                                    <Get class="javax.servlet.DispatcherType" name="REQUEST" />
                                </Arg>
                            </Call>
                        </Arg>
                    </Call>
                </New>
            </Arg>
        </Call>
    </Get>
```

**Filters configured in web.xml:**

```xml
    <filter>
            <filter-name>DoSFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.DoSFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>maxRequestsPerSec</param-name>
                    <param-value>1</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>delayMs</param-name>
                    <param-value>100</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>maxRequestMs</param-name>
                    <param-value>0</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>maxIdleTrackerMs</param-name>
                    <param-value>0</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>ipWhitelist</param-name>
                    <param-value>127.0.0.1</param-value>
            </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>DoSFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/cxf/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Is this not a web app for you to use web xml or jetty-web xml ? jetty xml used for configuring server.

Comment: Are you using a product like [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or [apache httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/) to proxy your jetty application?  If so, both those products have good ability to rate limit requests.

Comment: @user2683814, the project has a web.xml as well. I have even configured the filter in web.xml as well but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using embedded Jetty you do not need a jetty.xml file, instead you can configure this through API. Here is a code example which configures the DoSFilter with the same settings from your example in an embedded usage.

```
Server server = new Server();
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
server.addConnector(connector);

ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
contextHandler.setContextPath("/");
server.setHandler(contextHandler);

DoSFilter filter = new DoSFilter();
filter.setMaxRequestsPerSec(30);
contextHandler.addFilter(new FilterHolder(filter), "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

server.start();
server.join();
```

I would also suggest you update to the latest version of Jetty as jetty-9.2 is End of Life, the latest version is currently jetty-9.4.27.

Comment: Thanks @Lachlan. I am working on the existing project where they have a jetty.xml. It  has other server settings already. I have just added the QosFilter to it, but it is not working. I have updated my question with the options I have tried so far. Can you check whether I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: That web.xml configuration should work, I tested it and it works for me.
Can you give a jetty server dump (set -Djetty.server.dumpAfterStart=true)?

Also in the jetty.xml example you don't need to use init params there, you can call the setters on the DoS filter directly.